# MzInput with autocomplete and ngModel

Tags: angular, materialize

Im using the angular [ng2-materialize](https://sherweb.github.io/ng2-materialize) lib and i hit a snag when trying to use the autocomplete functionality on an input with ngModel:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'item-list',
    template: `
    <mz-input-container>
        <input mz-input [(ngModel)]="item" [autocomplete]="items" type="text">
    </mz-input-container>
    `
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    public item: string;
    public items: any;

    constructor(private service: MyService) {
        this.item = '';
        this.items = { data: {}, limit: 10 };
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.myservice.data.subscribe(data => {
            this.items.data = {};
            data.forEach(s => {
                this.items.data[s.name] = '';
            })
        });
    }
}
```

The completer works and shows a list of items and i can move through them with the keyboard or click one and the input value updates, however I can't seem to find a way to respond to the current value of the input as the model binding doesn't change.

Am i using this incorrectly or did i miss something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could bind a method to `ngModelChange`. For example `(ngModelChange)="respondToChange($event)"`. The value of `$event` will be the latest `ngModel` value.

That way when the model is updated you can perform whatever update logic you need.

To clarify:

```
<mz-input-container>
  <input mz-input [(ngModel)]="item" 
    (ngModelChange)="respondToChange($event)" [autocomplete]="items" 
    type="text">
</mz-input-container>
```

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't seem to grab the value of the input either, just the characters i actually typed in and not the completed string